# Missing Expression when performing correlated update

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update the names in one table with the matching names from a corresponding table if their ID numbers match.

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
    SET NAME = SELECT (t2.name 
                            FROM table2 t2
                                WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID);
```

This is the error that is returned:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

When running the select statement separately from the update it returns that `T1.id` is not a valid identifier even though it exists as a column in the table.

I feel like a I am matching the syntax from [PSOUG](http://psoug.org/reference/update.html).

Comment: Don't do it!  Store the `id` and look up the name when you need the name.  That is how relational databases work.

Comment: I am trying to fill in the missing names for the first table. The second table is just a temporary.

Answer (score 2):

The opening parenthesis needs to be before the `select`, not after it:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
SET NAME = (SELECT t2.name 
                        FROM table2 t2
                            WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID);
```

The whole subquery is inside the parentheses. Which is what the PSOUG page you linked to shows, in their third example, "Update based on a single queried value"; and what [the examples in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10008.htm#i2189756) show.

Quick demo, with simple table set-up:

```
create table table1 (id number, name varchar2(10));
insert into table1 values (1, null);
insert into table1 values (2, 'Old name');
insert into table1 values (3, null);

create table table2 (id number, name varchar2(10));
insert into table2 values (1, 'New name 1');
insert into table2 values (2, 'New name 2');
```

Your original code from the question gets:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
```

The code above works:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
SET NAME = (SELECT t2.name 
                        FROM table2 t2
                            WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID);

3 rows updated.

select * from table1;

        ID NAME     
---------- ----------
         1 New name 1
         2 New name 2
         3
```

---

From a comment you seem to think you might need to have another reference to `table1` in the subquery, but if you do that you lose the correlation between the update and the subquery rows, even if the table being updated still has an alias:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
SET NAME = (
  SELECT t2.name 
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.ID = t2.ID);

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

With this incorrect code the `table1` and `t1` alias in the subquery have no relationship to the `table1` or `t1` in the outer `update ...` clause.

Comment: @YungDouglas - the code in the answer does not throw ORA-00936, so no idea what you are doing differently.

Comment: I realized that I am not including the table that t1.ID should be coming from. if I add     table1 t1 after the from I get a subquery that returns more than one row. What is the proper syntax here?

Comment: @YungDouglas - t1 is the alias for the table you're updating, so not quite sure what you mean. The code here works. You don't want to repeat table1 in the subquery, you'd lose the correlation (hence getting multiple rows).

Comment: @YungDouglas - I've added an example showing it working. I'm still not sure what problem you're having; unless you left out the `t1` alias from the `update`, but you had that in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine only if in table2 for each id there is a unique name.

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
SET NAME = (SELECT t2.name 
                    FROM table2 t2
                        WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID);
```

Example:
The query returns in the following cases.If the table2 has values like

```
  name id
  x    1
  y    1
```

Comment: That code is exactly what I posted yesterday? But the name doesn't have to be unique, the ID had to be unique.